# What is real purpose of ismap attribute in img tag?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Never used ismap attribute in image tag ever.

Referred http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp and it says

> Specifies an image as a server-side
>   image-map. Rarely used. Look at usemap
>   instead

Since I'm a front end web developer, I may not have opportunity to use it.

Could any serverside guys please shed some light on it?

Answer (score 7):

You specify a map file as a target for an anchor containing the `ismap` image. The map file then defines target areas so that clicking on the image will take you to different pages depending on where you click.

[This tutorial](http://www.iupui.edu/~webtrain/tutorials/ismap.html) (the instructions are slightly IUPUI-specific, but the *basics* aren't) clarifies things a bit.

`usemap` is preferred though, I believe - see [this tutorial](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/images_famsupp_220.html) for an example of that.